# How is it possible for a const T& to refer to a literal?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, value-categories

My understanding is that a `const T&` is internally implemented via a `const T *const`. If so, how is the below code valid (since we cannot take the address of 7)?

```
const int& i = 7;
```

Or does the compiler does some trick here? If so, what?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong.

Comment: references are internally implemented to meet their specification. Wether there are pointers involved or not is irrelevant to judge if the code is valid, just saying

Comment: Don't forget the [As-if Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). The compiler will do anything to get you a faster program if you won't be able to tell the difference in the observable behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot take the address of a literal like `7` but you can take the address of a temporary object whose value is `7`.

Think of that line to be equivalent to

```
const int unnamed_temprary_variable = 7;
const int& i = unnamed_temprary_variable;
```

> Or does the compiler does some trick here? If so, what?

The compiler does something analogous to the two lines I mentioned but it is not a trick. It is required by the language.

Searching for "extending the lifetime of temporaries" in SO resulted in [a long list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+extending+the+lifetime+of+temporaries).